# Powerful gitk/gitg alternative?

Tags: git, user-interface, repository, viewer

I am searching for a graphical git repository viewer. Gitk is nice and distributed alongside git itself, gitg is a (in my opinion) better alternative to gitk but both have a lack of features (searching for commits/tags/..., switiching/configuring the representation of time(zones) and so on).

As I am doing all git stuff directly in the terminal I do not need some overloaded GUI who tries to do all the magic of git, I just want an efficient viewer for graphical representation of my files, commits, branches, tags and so on with more features than gitk/gitg.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Most times I'm working on linux.

Comment: Have you already enter 'git gui' on your shell ?

Comment: After entering `git gui`: `git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: You need to install it. 'sudo aptitude install git-gui gitk'.

Comment: git gui is a graphical tool for manipulating the current branch tip (making commits, etc.).  gitk is for browsing an existing history.

Comment: I've just asked a [somewhat similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/80877/15631), but with other requirements, on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this question really has its place here, but if you want recommendations, I can link you to [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) or [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) if you're on Windows or Mac, or [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) if you're on Windows.

Edit : As it seems like people are still looking at that answer, I can now also recommend [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/).

Comment: thank you, but most of the time I'm working on linux...should've mentioned that.

Comment: GitExtensions is the *only* Git UI I've used that I actually recommend (2018-2020). Many others are too slow/awkward or too cute/limited. That said, I do most all "actions" from the CLI; the UI makes a great branch navigator..

Comment: I just tried GitKraken and it requires setting up an account, so that seems a lot more intrusive than gitk.

Answer (score 4):

SmartGit is an alternative. It works on Windows, Mac OS and Linux:

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

Comment: It is Java, JFYI.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 the best choice is QGIT if you have to handle a huge repository on Linux. With QGIT you can set up a commit range so it won't load all the old commits. Install with:  sudo apt install qgit

Answer (score 1):

Late answer.

I have been a big fan of [GitAhead](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead) which entered maintenance by the end of 2021.

Since then, the main fork of it is [Gittyup](https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup).

Pros:

- **blazing** fast and low resource usage comparatively to some of the alternatives (GitKraken, MS vScode, …)
- (arguably) cuter than gitk and qgit
- cross-platform (like most of the others, but worth noting)
- [ready to use binaries](https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup/releases) and available on flathub
- lots of features
- Open-Source!

Comment: Ready to use binaries but no Debian package, not even tar.gz. Some strange containerized setup doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to gitk:

- [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (free)
- [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) (licensed)

> lack of features (searching for commits/tags/ ... I am doing all git stuff directly in the terminal

`git tag -l <pattern>`

`git log --all --grep='<commit message>'`

Comment: GitKraken is free for non-commercial individuals, as is GitAhead.

Answer (score 0):

Git Cola is a sleek and powerful graphical user interface for Git.
Git Cola is free software and written in Python (v2 + v3).

https://git-cola.github.io/

https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola

It is available in most of Linux Repos too.

For example, For Debian/Ubuntu based distros use this command.

```
sudo apt install git-cola
```